# IPTables How do I block a specific UDP Packet?

Tags: linux, udp, iptables, centos5, netfilter

I was wondering if it's possible to block this particular packet in IPTables?

```
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 122, id 59478, offset 0, flags [none], proto: **UDP** (17), **length: 32**) 49.125.39.7.53125 > 68.68.27.40.34535: UDP, **length 0**
    0x0000:  4500 0020 e856 0000 7a11 a086 317d 2707  E....V..z...1}'.
    0x0010:  4444 1b28 cf85 86e7 0008 0000 0000 0000  DD.(............
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

IP (tos 0x0, ttl  43, id 42852, offset 0, flags [none], proto: UDP (17), length: 32) 15.205.231.92.63002 > 68.68.27.40.18287: UDP, length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0020 a764 0000 2b11 91d3 0fcd e75c  E....d..+......\
    0x0010:  4444 1b28 f61a 476f 0008 0000 0000 0000  DD.(..Go........
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

It's a spoofed DoS attack, with random source IPs to random destination ports, exhausting the udp ports our server application needs. I want to block the packet according to the highlighted parts of the tcp dump, namely UDP length:32 + length 0 at the end. Is that possible?

Or is it possible to block the packets by the hex-string in the dump?

Thank you kindly,
Floyd

Answer (score 0):

The IPTables have a `u32` module to test whether quantities of up to 4 bytes extracted from a packet have specified values.
You might be able to test the packet is DoS attachek or not.
Below is an example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -m u32 --u32 "16 & 0xFFFF = 0x4444"
```

See [manpage of iptables](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) (you should use `man iptables` on your environment) for more detail.

Comment: Is the u32 module available in centos5?

Comment: @Floyd, yes u32 module is available in CentOS 5 (I checked on my CentOS 5.3 hosts). See `man iptables` for more information.

Comment: `[root@dbox ~]# iptables -m u32 -h
iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load match u32':/lib/iptables/libipt_u32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` I see u32 mention in the manpages, but apparently the module's missing CentOS 5.7, does that mean I'd have to recompile the kernel?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems that kernel should be recompiled.